# Smallest odd number in given array

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop

This code is supposed to find the smallest odd number in given array and store it in `min` but when I try to print `min` it always prints `0`.

```
int smallestodd(int x[5]){
  int j;
  int k[5];
  int p = 0;
  int r = 0;

  for(int h =0; h<5;h++){

    j = x[h] % 2;
    if(j == 1){
      int temp =x[h];
      k[p] =temp;
      p++;
    }
  }

  int min = k[0];


  while(k[r] !=0){
    if(k[r] < min ){
      min = k[r];
      r++;
    }
  }

  return min;
}
```

Comment: You have infinite loop as you update `r` in `if(k[r] < min )` and `min` is initialized to `k[0]`.

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This doesn't print anything.

Comment: why do you keep k[] it would be enough to initialize min to the first element in x (or some large value) and then look through the rest, if smaller and odd, assign to min

Comment: Also note that local variables (including arrays) are not automatically initialized. Uninitialized variables will have *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) values. That means the loop condition `k[r] !=0` is wrong (since there might not be any element equal to zero in the array). You have the number of valid elements in `k` in the variable `p`. Use it.

Comment: `int min = k[0];`, what if the first element is even? Oops.

Comment: first element can't be even because it only stores odd ones but it doesn't matter anyways due to @Someprogrammerdude's answer

Comment: @Touche. Have an upvote as I've trolled the question.

Comment: @kiranBiradar what do you mean? min is k[0] and that if statement checks if k[r] is smaller than the min, shouln't it just pass the first one because it's the same value as min? why would it be a infinite loop

Comment: `if(j == 1){` will not detect odd values when `x[h]` is a negative odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there is an odd number in the array -- *let's say trying to find the minimum odd number in an array with just even numbers (or no numbers) is UB* :)

```
index = 0;
while (arr[index] % 2 == 0) index++; // skip even numbers
min = arr[index++]; // first odd number
while (index < length) {
    if (arr[index] % 2) {
        if (arr[index] < min) min = arr[index];
    }
    index++;
}
```

Comment: this looks like it's working but when i compile it kinda doesn't sometimes gives the right number but it even gave even number once i don't understand, can you  write the whole code for this ?

Comment: See [https://ideone.com/ReMpmO](https://ideone.com/ReMpmO); I had a little bug in the first version, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

this code avoid overflow in search and return 1 when found or 0 if array has only even numbers.

```
int getMinOdd(int arr[], int length, int *value) {
    int found = 0;
    for(int idx=0; idx < length; idx++) {
        if (arr[idx] % 2) {
            if (!found || *value > arr[idx]) {
                *value = arr[idx];
            }
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually. You need to just check 2 conditions on your array.

```
int smallestOdd(int arr[]){
    int min = 99999; //Some very large number
    for(int i = 0; i < (length of your array); i++) {
        if(arr[i]%2 != 0 && arr[i] < min) { //Check if number is odd and less than the current minimum value
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: `int min = 99999;` - this gives me chills

Comment: this is working  thanks but i need to find the algorithm that works for everything.

Comment: Instead of 99999, better to use the largest `int` - which is odd: `int min = INT_MAX;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this using statement as first :

Using System Linq;

Console.WriteLine(myArray.Where(i => i%2 == 1).Min());